# How do you bleed the air out of a Grundfos UPS15-58FC Circulating Pump?

Tags: plumbing, water, boiler, hot-water, pump

[image]

My Grundfos UPS15-58FC has become a bit noisy when operational. Its a part of my heating system and it starts to hum from time to time and this causes the pipe its on to vibrate. I would like to try and bleed the air out of it. Correct me if I’m wrong but this seems to be the way to go with circulating pumps. Is it possible to bleed the air out of it? It seems to have plastic covering where the pump bleed screw would normally be and it says “With Check Valve”…I’m a bit lost - I was expecting a pump bleed screw and I’m not sure I see how a check valve prevents air from building up from the inlet. Can somebody please shed some light? I’m afraid of trying to pry out the plastic cover - it seems to be on very tight - in case that breaks the thing.

Edit:

[image]

I found a manual bleed valve at the top of my water loop and I slowly turned the small nob on the side until a bit of water came out (circled at the top right), then screwed it back in. I also ran some hot water through the pump by opening the red valve (circled at the bottom left) which rests under the Grundfos (arrow points to the Grundfos). Will report back in a few days, or if anyone else has more suggestions, please feel free!

Comment: you probably have to bleed some nearby pipe.  how is your pump installed?

Comment: @Jasen Its connected to the hot water pipe. Water flows down in this pipe. The inlet at the top of the unit has a shut-off valve located above the unit. The outlet at the bottom of the unit also has a shut-off valve located below the unit. Beyond the shut-off valve there is a drain valve on the pipe. Should I shut the top valve off and then open that drain with the bottom valve open?

Comment: I've never seen a circulator with a bleed valve, and never seen or heard of anyone bleeding one.  I did  just now watch the youtube video that you probably have, of someone bleeding air out of a pump similar to the one in your picture, except that one has a screw and yours doesn't.  I'm mystified as to why it would be necessary.  Maybe if the circulator is installed horizontally with the motor housing facing upwards???  But if it's installed as in your picture, the bleed valve would need to be somewhere above it in the pipework.

Comment: No.  The opposite.  When you bleed the system the air needs to be replaced with water.  The water supply needs to be on and the water pressure, from it, needs to be high enough to push air out of the highest point in the system. (Top of the highest radiator).  Otherwise it won't bleed.

Comment: @jay613 I’ve edited the question and added what I’ve done so far along with a picture of the setup. Please let me know if that sounds okay!

Comment: I've never encountered a circulator needing bleeding and never had this specific vibration problem so not sure I can help much more.  All I really had to offer is that if there is air being trapped in the vicinity of the boiler and nearby equipment, it has to be bled from a local high point in the pipework.

Comment: @jay613 No worries. I’ve also been thinking to descale and clean the filter on the tankless unit at some point, since that’s also part of the loop. Ultimately, if it keeps being noisy, I’ll probably change the pump or try running it on medium. Its always been on high.

Answer (score 1):

Air vents in hot water circulation systems are, or should be, located at high points (sometimes local high points) in the system. They are pretty much never right at the pump, in my experience.

Depending where the hot water loop runs, the appropriate vents might be on the other side of the house, or two stories above the pump. There is usually one near the boiler, typically on top of an "air scoop" which typically has an expansion tank on its underside, but there are many variants. The rest tend to be tucked on at the highest elbows in the system, often hidden behind baseboard covers if baseboard heat, or at the high parts of hot water radiators.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/77954/18078 for a minimalist, manual, bleeder valve. Here's a radiator bleed and automatic bleeder: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/214591/18078 details of automatic bleeder: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/211007/18078

Comment: I actually have a tankless system by Rinnai. This particular circulating pump sends hot water into the air handler and then returns cold water back out by the looks of it.

Comment: I updated the question with some images, in case you may have any more suggestions for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm troubleshooting mine right now.  Something wrong with the pump itself.  Will likely need to replace.  However, regarding your question about the plastic cover, don't worry about it.  It's *very* tight, and removing it gives you access to nothing.  The motor and pump are integral.  The part that comes off is the permanent magnet electrical portion.

Comment: In the end, replaced all the Uponor plumbing because some parts where plumbing created peaks above the height of the rest of the PEX plumbing were trapping air. I also added an air eliminator on the cold intake of the boiler and some valves to close the HVAC loop with the expansion tank in the loop. Also realized one of my check valves were very noisy so replaced it. I think one of these many changes solved my issue. It probably wasn’t the Grundfos afterall…

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/152522)